# How to return an API response n times after calling it in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, rest

I have been using python 3x and made an API as below:

```
@app.route('/testapi', methods=['POST'])
def test_api():
    try:
        response = {'MSG': "Works"}
        return response
    except:
        return False
```

I have been calling this API from javascript, Once I call the /testapi , it should return the response n(eg:4) times with a time delay of 10 seconds. How can I achieve this solution?

Comment: are you using ajax for it?

Comment: yes correct@charchit

Answer (score 1):

You can then use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) for this.

```
var x = 0;
var intervalID = setInterval(function () {

   // Your logic for calling api here

   if (++x === 4) { // call four times times
       window.clearInterval(intervalID);
   }
}, 10000);// 1 sec == 1000ms
```

Comment: I am expecting the answer in python. But still this seems to be good! Thank you@charchit.

Comment: I don't think there is something in python to do so. maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Yes same thoughts.